# Magic poltergeist div in front of whole body in GWT app with GXT

Tags: javascript, css, gwt, gxt

GWT is continually appending and removing a div from the DOM that covers the entire viewport.  The div has inline styling such that it not only covers the entire screen, but also has a z-index in chrome of 2^32. (I bet it has one 2^64 in 64 bit browsers).  The div is the last element within the body tag, so I am able to hide by targeting body div:last-child in CSS, but that's obviously less than an ideal solution.

I am using the GXT neptune theme, but this occurs in views with no GXT widgets as well.

Has anyone else ever seen such craziness and lived to solve it?  Is this a known bug?

Comment: Can you post the element's html code?

Comment: <div style="position:absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; z-index: 2147483647"; opacity: 0; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></div>

Comment: Sounds a bit like the GWT dialog 'glass', since it is totally transparent (though that doesn't get zindex set, and has a class), but created to be the highest up element. Check if it is part of a widget in your browser tools by examining if `element.__listener` (two underscores) exists, and if so, try invoking toString on it to see if it gives you any more detail. Other than that, knowing what other js or gwt scripts/inherits/libs you have would help.

Comment: Could you provide a test case with the issue?

Comment: Hey @erfling am kind of having the same issue with my current application, just want to ask have you solved your issue. If so please kindly assist